# How to make the links open in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make each of these links open in a new tab instead of opening on my website tab?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var plinks = [
    {
        name: 'ady',
        plink: 'http://steamcommunity.com/id/42432'
    },
    {
        name: 'moon',
        plink: 'http://steamcommunity.com/id/22242'
    },
    {
        name: 'internal',
        plink: 'http://steamcommunity.com/id/2424'
    },
    {   name: 'silvatone',
        plink: 'http://steamcommunity.com/id/4324234'

    },
];
```

for(var i in plinks) {
        var plink = plinks[i];

```
    $('#marquee').append('<a href="' + plink.plink + '">' + plink.name + '</a>');

    var plink = $('#marquee').children('a').last();

    if(i != plinks.length - 1) {
        $('#marquee').append(' - ');
    }
}
```

Comment: add target attribute to each link target="_blank"

Comment: That would depend how those links are used.... in an `anchor` tag? via javascript with `window.open()`? Either way the target method should be `_blank`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add with [`target="_blank"`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjxh_XP9IzUAhUBpY8KHUL_BLoQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Ftags%2Fatt_a_target.asp&usg=AFQjCNGNcJsyH74LBuBJPIp9X_yv4se00w&sig2=9Ikvc6YqpG5q8yd6Yac1RQ) on the append `a tag`

Form more simplified version .DO with [`Array#map`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi1iZaF9ozUAhULt48KHfYnBrwQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap&usg=AFQjCNHaY16WQvsRJFKI1AN9YJUvUNjsCg&sig2=sy1VMQqJUnBES6ZN7uOzFw) and [`Array#join()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiUmdaN9ozUAhUFRY8KHZRiD2MQFggrMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fjoin&usg=AFQjCNFpvATQJoPTs0sJsk78ojioE7D3Xg&sig2=KoabSyoMioyYeSlYWCnLfw) method

```
  var res = plinks.map(function(a) { 
           return '<a href="' + a.plink + '"  target="_blank">' + a.name + '</a>';
            })
            $('#marquee').append(res.join('-'))
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var plinks = [{
        name: 'ady',
        plink: 'http://steamcommunity.com/id/42432'
      }, {
        name: 'moon',
        plink: 'http://steamcommunity.com/id/22242'
      }, {
        name: 'internal',
        plink: 'http://steamcommunity.com/id/2424'
      }, {
        name: 'silvatone',
        plink: 'http://steamcommunity.com/id/4324234'
      }, ];
      
      for (var i in plinks) {
        var plink = plinks[i];

        $('#marquee').append('<a href="' + plink.plink + '"  target="_blank">' + plink.name + '</a>');

        var plink = $('#marquee').children('a').last();

        if (i != plinks.length - 1) {
          $('#marquee').append(' - ');
        }
      }
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="marquee"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using window.open

**CODE**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var plinks = [
    {
    name: 'ady',
    plink: 'http://steamcommunity.com/id/42432'
    },
    {
    name: 'moon',
    plink: 'http://steamcommunity.com/id/22242'
    },
    {
     name: 'internal',
    plink: 'http://steamcommunity.com/id/2424'
    },
    {   
    name: 'silvatone',
    plink: 'http://steamcommunity.com/id/4324234'
    },
   ];
   for(var i=0;i<plinks.length;i++){
      window.open(plinks[i]['plink'],'_blank')
   }
})
```

Comment: I'm  pretty sure using `plinks['plink']` will return **undefined**, shouldn't it be `plinks[i].plink` or `plinks[i]['plink']`?

Comment: Oops.Changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `target=_blank` in the anchor tag.

E.g.

```
<a target="_blank">
```